# I am getting a "Bad response from Chimp Server" in my console when trying to run a meteor app with velocity/cucumber testing on it

Tags: testing, meteor, cucumber, velocity

The error is not in my regular console, it's in my tail -f console. It won't run the tests at all. In my localhost:3000 velocity sidebar it also says chimp server error. I am not sure how to fix this, I am very new to velocity and cucumber so it could be a stupid mistake, but I couldn't find any information on this error anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide us with the whole meteor log and also cucumber log? If possible - please do meteor reset first (be aware though that this will clean up your local mongodb, if you want to avoid that, at least clean the cucumber log - `echo '' > filePath` will work )

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem yesterday while trying to follow Josh Owen's now outdated cucumber tutorial. The error was coming from with the step definition file while not wrapping `module.exports` in a function like this:

```
(function() {

    module.exports = function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

It could also be that your test directory and files aren't structured correctly in your app.

It should look like this:

```
app/
  tests/
    cucumber/
      features/
        step_definitions/
          my_steps.js
        my_feature.feature
      fixtures/
        my_fixture.js
```

Let me know if that makes a difference. Also, this is a good place to start with velocity/cucumber: http://www.mhurwi.com/a-basic-cucumber-meteor-tutorial/

It's very basic but there isn't much out there for learning testing with Meteor.